# Why is it not possible to go into BIOS on a cloud server?

Tags: cloud-computing

I am trialling cloudsigma, and they claim to use a KVM Hypervisor. I have a trial server, but cannot boot it from BIOS. Is this the case with all cloud servers?

The company claims I can run Hyper-V or ESX, but I would not be able to without going into BIOS first.

Thanks

Comment: You can not run Hyper-V on top of a hyper-visor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a BIOS in most VMs (and certainly not in KVM).  I mean, there's something that works as a BIOS, but it's not going to be the "press F2 to set some stuff up" BIOS that you're used to.

If you're wanting to set boot parameters or something, they'll have to do it for you.

Comment: Actually, VMWare Workstation (maybe others, I've never checked) **do** have an emulated BIOS that you can press a key to enter into.

Comment: Ok, but KVM certainly doesn't.  The question does say "they claim to use a KVM Hypervisor" :)

Answer (score 2):

ESX/i lets any VM go into BIOS - speak to them about this ok.